# New 14.04.4 LTS server install got kernel 4.2

Tags: system-installation, kernel

I installed 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS server on a box just now and it has version 4.2.x of the Linux kernel. Why? I thought 14.04 LTS would use a 3.13 kernel unless I took extra steps to install an LTS enablement stack. Did I somehow accidentally tell it to install a 4.2.x kernel during the install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04.4 comes with kernel 4.2.

It is all correct with your installation.

Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.04.1 were shipped with kernel 3.13.

14.04.2 with kernel 3.16

14.04.3 with 3.19.

See [LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack):

> The Ubuntu LTS enablement stacks provide newer kernel and X support for existing LTS releases. These can be installed manually, or are automatically shipped if installing from 12.04.2/14.04.2 and newer release media.

Comment: Ah! So, I also have another 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 box that has been upgraded from 14.04.1 to 14.04.4. Why didn't that one get the 4.2 kernel?

Comment: [This page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) just answered my own question. Will you add this quote to your answer, then I'll accept it? "The Ubuntu LTS enablement stacks provide newer kernel and X support for existing LTS releases. These can be installed manually, or are automatically shipped if installing from 12.04.2/14.04.2 and newer release media."

Comment: This is done...

Comment: I gave this link a few times already in other answers.

Comment: Feel free to mark this as a duplicate if that is more appropriate.